# Why does Bitcoin Core verify already verified blocks?

Tags: bitcoin-core, validation

I have observed that when I restart my Raspberry Pi, which I had left at a specific height (for example, 800,000), the software starts verifying the last x blocks, beginning from a point prior to height 800,000. Why does this occur since it had already verified those prior to 800,000?

Answer (score 1):

It does that as a consistency check to be more sure that the data stored on disk was not modified or otherwise corrupted in the time the node was offline.